# Django unit testing form with field assigned from request object

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

I have this form

```
class PostCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

and I'm trying to unit test it with this test

```
class PostCreationByFormTestCase(TestCase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PostCreationByFormTestCase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.CustomUser = get_user_model()

    def setUp(self):
        self.credentials = {
            'username': 'john_smith',
            'password': 'St0ngPassw0rd'
        }
        self.user = self.CustomUser.objects.create(
            username=self.credentials['username'],
            email='john_smith@mail.com',
            password=self.credentials['password'],
            first_name='John',
            last_name='Smith'
        )

    def test_simple_form(self):
        form_data = {
            'author': self.user,
            'title': 'Simple Post',
            'description': 'very good description',
        }
        form = PostCreationForm(form_data)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid)
        post = form.save()
```

the assert passes, but the `form.save()` produces
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "author_id" violates not-null constraint

I tried changing the form to

```
class PostCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        if not form.instance.author:
            form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

but it still does not work. I saw this as a recommended way to assign field to object if I don't want to take it as an input from the user as in this case where I want the author of the post to be the current user.
How should I fix that in order to be able to test the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When checking whether a form is valid you need to call the **method** `is_valid`, it is not a property. Changing `form.is_valid` to `form.is_valid()` will work.

`form_valid()` however will not be called when you check for `form.is_valid()`, so you probably want to use the `clean` methods. An untested example:

```
class PostCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean_author(self):
        author = self.cleaned_data.get('author')
        if not author:
            author = self.request.user
        return author
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn for noticing that typo! Unfortunately even when I fixed it the assertion still passes, but the `form.save()` produces the integrationError

Comment: Oh yeah you should use the `clean()` methods instead of `form_valid`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Okay I think I undestand what the problem Is. I want the `author` field to be autoassigned on post creation, so I made the field `editable=False` in the model and then assign it in the view using the `request.user`, but now I think this makes the form hard if not impossible to test, isn't it?

Comment: I too think it's better to assign the author in the view but I've updated my answer with an alternative that uses `clean`. (Note that I didn't test this code.) Regarding testing, I don't see any problem?

Comment: I really like that solution and was thinking of something like this, but does it actually make sense? In the unit test testing the form I dont have request object and the form is used out of any view, so what does `self.request` mean then?

Comment: When unit testing you'd have to mock the request. Something as simple as `request = MagicMock(user='your_test_user')` could already be enough. You could also tests the http request, and then the testing client would set up a request for you which will then have whatever user you authenticated in the test as `request.user`.

Comment: Okay, I think I will take that approach! Thank you for your help!